# WPF multiple ID's with Datagrid Checkboxes

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I'm working on a school project right now where I wanted to challenge myself, so I thought myself how to work with WPF Applications but I ran into an issue which I can't figure out myself.  The issue I'm having is, that I can't select multiple ID's from the row where the checkboxes are checked.

What should the program do with the IDs?

1. Select x ID's
2. Open a new window foreach found ID

Pictures showing the program:

[Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpnXT.png)

[Designer Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXLxe.png)

So if the user presses one of the buttons on the topleft after selecting **at least** one row with a checkbox the program should select the ID's from the column[0] "Kunden-Nr". I can only manage to do it with a single row with a `doubleclick` event which selects the value from the first column of the selected row.

Datagrid Designer code for people that don't want to open the picture.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <DataGrid x:Name="dgvCustomerOverview" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KD_NR}" Header="Kunden-Nr" Width="0.7*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KD_Name}" Header="Name" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Geburtstag" Width="*">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource dgvPadding}" Text="{Binding KD_Gebtag, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy\}}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KD_Plz}" Header="Postleitzahl" Width="0.75*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KD_Ort}" Header="Ort" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KD_Strasse}" Header="Straße" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KD_HausNr}" Header="Haus-Nr" Width="0.55*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KD_Email}" Header="E-Mail" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KD_Privattel}" Header="Tel. Privat" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KD_Mobiltel}" Header="Tel. Mobil" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Auswählen" Width="0.75*"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

In DataGrid, you can use SelectedItem="{Binding MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" and will obtain selected row